# How to call a method when a select box is initialized in an Angular app

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have used a select box inside a row. The row is generated using a loop. I need to call a method when this select box is 
initialized. This method will pass the dynamically generated row data as an argument.
I am confused as to how this can be achieved in Angular4/5.

In AngularJS it could be done like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in myData track by $index">
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="row.val" ng-init="methodToCall(row)">
</tr>
```

Comment: Interesting, i would suggest use your own component so you can implement the `ngOnInit`.

Comment: update post with `methodToCall()` method

Comment: @Sanoj in the methodToCall() method, I need to work something on the row data that is passed. I think its logic is irrelevant.

Comment: Imo , if you need to do something for each `row` of `myData` at component initialization, you can just do it in `ngAfterViewInit`, it's happening after all components are loaded. Only problem I can think of is if you want to do something with the `select` component itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might use my own component for that purpose:

So create new component as follow:

```
import {Component, onInit, Input} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
     selector: "custom-select"
 })
export class customeSelect implements onInit{
      @Input() row:any;
      ngOnInit(){
         //You can call what ever you want after your component initialized.
         console.log(this.row);
      }
}
```

and use it in your `ngfor` like below:

```
<tr *ngFor="row in myData">
    <custom-select [row]="row"></custom-select>
</tr>
```

Comment: How do you transmit `row` to customSelect ?

Comment: @SebastienServouze can you explain more what do you mean please ?

Comment: @Nour How will I pass the row data to ngOnInit or some other method in this component?

Comment: OP needs to do something with `row` variable at each `<select>` initialization. So, you need a way to pass it dynamically to your custom component

Comment: Please check angular documentation to know how components interaction works. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: There you go :) (passing data to component part was missing, now it's here ;))

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think this is all I needed.

Comment: Glad to help :)